# using gammu and a DKU2 cable to write a vCard to a nokia 6303i classic

Tags: send, vcf-vcard, gammu

I am trying out `gammu` for the 1st time because I want to transfer some google contacts back to a nokia 6303i .

While the [phone database section](http://wammu.eu/phones/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=N3unFVzCHROCxUuWyjqZPOQo9V95GQUn&q=nokia%206303i&submit=Search) in Gammu website states that a number of bluetooth connection settings can be used with this phone, I have no bluetooth connection and will thus have to resort to a DKU2 usb cable that I have. The cable is actually a CA-101 nokia cable but according to [gnokii wiki](http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/Cables) they are technically the same.

I have attempted several different connection types. from the `~/.gammurc`

```
[gammu]

#model = NAUTO
device = 01a5:-1
connection = dku2
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = gammu0.log
logformat = text
use_locking =
gammuloc =

[gammu1]


device = /dev/ttyACM0
connection = at
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = gammu1.log
logformat = text
use_locking =
gammuloc =

[gammu2]

#model = NAUTO
device = /dev/ttyACM0
connection = fbus
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = gammu2.log
logformat = text
use_locking =
gammuloc =

[gammu3]

#model = NAUTO
device = 01a5:-1
connection = fbususb
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = gammu2.log
logformat = text
use_locking =
gammuloc =
```

I have managed to use the "at" connection with `gammu -s 1 identify` and correctly read phone info. Then I tried to copy a simple (albeit non gammu generated) vCard from those I exported from google contacts.

It was typically formatted like so:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:Name Surname
N:Surname;Name
EMAIL;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=8BIT:name.surname@domain.com
TEL;TYPE=CELL:+10123456789
TEL;TYPE=CELL:+19876543210
END:VCARD
```

What is frustrating is that from a Windows Pc running nokia PC suite I was able to correctly send that same vCard to the nokia 6303i over the same cable. 
However from gammu I have -at most- been able to send the surname from the "N:Surname;Name;;;" field (the contact only shows up with the surname) and the 1st telephone number. So the email and the 2nd phone number have been omitted.

This is not enough for me , because I need all phones, all emails and notes to be transferred. I have not found any information abotu whether the "at" connection supports the "enhancedphonebook" functionality (it appears that it does not), but I apart from "bluefbus" which supposedly supported the "enhancedphonebook" in the "Nokia 6303i Cliassic" I don't know which other **cabled** connection supports it.

so I have tried
the variations gammu(0) , gammu2 and gammu3 as seen in the config file

but these two do not work.
The `gammu` and `gammu3` dump the following in the log

```
[Gammu            - 1.31.0 built 12:51:10 Jul 24 2016 using GCC 4.7]
[Connection       - "dku2"] #or "fbususb for gammu3
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "01a5:-1"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.2.29-gaze5 (#1 SMP Sat Apr 20 13:57:31 EEST 2013)]
Checking 1d6b:0002 (bus 1, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0002 (bus 2, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0001 (bus 3, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0001 (bus 4, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0001 (bus 5, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0001 (bus 6, device 1)
Checking 1d6b:0001 (bus 7, device 1)
Checking 0421:0359 (bus 7, device 35)
Extra CDC subheader: 171
Trying to open device, config=1, c_iface=2, c_alt=0, d_iface=3, d_alt=1
Configuration change not required, unhooking only required interfaces!
Detaching kernel driver from inteface 2
Claiming USB control interface...
Configuring USB control interface...
Claiming USB data interface...
Configuring USB data interface...
Connected!
[Module           - "auto"]
Getting model
SENDING frametype 0xD1/length 0x05/5
00 |01 |00 |03 |00                                              .....
Failed to read from usb (-99)!
Other error
Failed to read from usb (-99)!
Other error
Failed to read from usb (-99)!
Other error
```

and `gammu2`

```
[Gammu            - 1.31.0 built 12:51:10 Jul 24 2016 using GCC 4.7]
[Connection       - "fbus"]
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "/dev/ttyACM0"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.2.29-gaze5 (#1 SMP Sat Apr 20 13:57:31 EEST 2013)]
Setting speed to 115200
Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is down, CAR is down, CTS is up
(... and it gets stuck here)
```

So the main question is: how can I achieve transferring the vCard (and many others) to the phone, over a usb cable???????

Thank you

Comment: I think dku2 should be correct choice here (http://wammu.eu/phones/nokia/4230/ seems to think that as well). Are there any USB errors in the kernel log?

Comment: @MichalČihař `dku2` or `dku2phonet` ?

Comment: These are equivalent (see https://github.com/gammu/gammu/blob/master/libgammu/gsmstate.c#L135).

Comment: @MichalČihař ok so what could be wrong and I cannot read from the usb?

Comment: Have you looked at kernel logs if there are any errors as I've suggested before?